# Motherboard upgrade necessary?

Tags: motherboard, upgrade

My PC configuration is as follows:

- Intel D102GGC2 motherboard.
- Intel Pentium D820.
- 80 GB HDD.
- 2 GB RAM.

Does my motherboard support 500 GB HDD and a 2GB graphics card, or do I need an upgrade?

Comment: If it helps, this is the manual: http://downloadmirror.intel.com/15112/eng/D102GGC2_TechProdSpec.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Well, it has PCI-E x16 for the video card, and Sata for the HDD. I'd note though a 2gb video card is overkill for a system of the vintage - I'd suggest considering either a current generation or previous generation low end card - which seem to have a gig of video ram for most part.